# Adding a Label to a Span in Bokeh 0.12

Tags: python, bokeh

How can I add a label to a span annotations within Bokeh? So far, I've seen labels by themselves, is there a better way to tie the labels to the spans?

Answer (score 8):

If you want a label attached to Span, you just need to set the location to be the same.

```
from bokeh.models import Span, Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400)

# Initialize your span and label
my_span = Span(location=0, dimension='height')
p.renderers.extend([my_span,])

my_label = Label(x=0, y=200, y_units='screen', text='Test label')
p.add_layout(my_label)
```

**Note** In this example, this label's `y` coordinates are specified in pixel coordinates by using the `y_units=screen` argument. It could also be in plot coords, just don't pass the `screen` argument.

Then, you can update their position like so:

```
def update():
    my_span.set(location=my_slider.value)
    my_label.set(x=my_slider.value)
```

For reference:

- [Label docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels)
- [Span docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.Span)